# Does out of the box software use GPU for numerics?

Tags: python, numpy, wolfram-mathematica, scipy, gpu

Needing a new desktop, the tech guy at my university bookstore suggests a xeon processor with a Tesla GPU unit. Does out-of-the-box software like Python, NumPy, SciPy, R, Stata, and Mathematica use the GPU for numerics?  Is there any reason for a regular user to have a special GPU unit?

Comment: numpy can be built with various low-level libraries such as ATLAS. If these libraries support using the GPU then numpy will use it too. Unfortunately I've never tried to build numpy with this kind of support so I cannot tell you whether you can find a GPU-aware, numpy-compatible library.

Comment: some do, change numpy-->[theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/).

Answer (score 1):

What will you be using the machine for? What kind of computing are you doing that needs an extreme amount of parallelization. A Xeon chip and Tesla GPU (but really just the GPU) will set you back at least $2000, but more likely $3000-4000, without any other components. If you really want to buy a CUDA supported card, you may want to consider a Nvidia 780/790 instead, or you could also try something like an AMD 7970. Check out some [benchmarks](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/geforce-gtx-780-performance-review,3516-26.html).

If you are at a university, ask one of the department tech guys (CS, physics, computational chemistry, computational biology, math, even finance). Also see if your campus has a local cluster or has access to a national or cloud cluster. There may be much better, and more affordable, options available to you if you're at university.